# How to use Image.GetBounds for List of images?

Tags: c#, winforms

Attempting to react to user click on any of a list of images which are on the WinForm (no pictureboxes used). I'm using GetBounds to check the location against the image area, walking through the list. I thought what I had should work, but after tinkering and reading online for a couple of hours I cannot see why it doesn't work.

imgPos is a list of Image type, starmap has been set to true.

```
 private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (starmap == true)
        {
            GraphicsUnit unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            foreach (Image pic in imgPos)
            {
                if (pic.GetBounds(ref unit).Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Clicked on image.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Help appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Image size (`GetBounds`) and position on the screen have no relation to each other... You should figure out how to convert one to another (I.e. is image shown at offset (100,300) from top of the window and scrolled so only last 1/10 of image shown - consider both to properly adjust location).

Comment: I thought getbounds returned the rectangle area and contains would return if the point was within that area?

Comment: An `Image` class doesn't contain the `Location` property because it isn't a descendant of the `Control`. Therefore its `GetBounds` method always returns a rectangle that is located at (0; 0).

Comment: @DarkMalice - indeed "getbounds returned the rectangle area and contains would return true if the point was within that area" is true, but for the check to be useful point need to be in the same coordinate system as bounding rectangle - one with (0,0) at top left corner of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to clarify the following moment. What does it mean?

> list of images which are on the WinForm

Image is an instance of the `System.Drawing.Image` class, right?
Since it is not a `Control`, it cannot be placed on a form. It may only be drawn in the form's `Paint` event handler. If so, you should store locations of images manually in the code, and compare them to the mouse's coordinates in the `MouseUp` event handler.
The sample code:

```
private readonly List<Point> imageLocations = new List<Point>();
private readonly List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add 1 empty image...
    images.Add(new Bitmap(100, 100));
    // ...and its location on the form.
    imageLocations.Add(new Point(10, 10));
}

private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Image image in images)
        if (new Rectangle(imageLocations[i++], image.Size).Contains(e.Location))
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked on image.");
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Image image in images)
            g.DrawImage(image, imageLocations[i++]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited slightly to suit my own, but this solution works perfectly. More importantly I can understand exactly how and why it works. Thank you Dmitry.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need to translate the screen coordinate `e.Location` into the same coordinate plane as the image.  Thus:

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (starmap == true)
    {
        GraphicsUnit unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

        foreach (Image pic in imgPos)
        {
            Rectangle imgRect = pic.GetBounds(ref unit);
            if (imgRect.Contains(this.PointToClient(e.Location)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Clicked on image.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick here is the `PointToClient` method.  Whatever you are drawing the `Image` onto, that is what goes where `this` is now.  I used `this` because I assume it's the `Form1` that you are drawing on.  If not, replace with the proper control reference.

Comment: Mmm. I used it as RectangleF as Rectangle was giving an error. Although it runs I'm still not getting the detection (no messagebox). Do I maybe need to draw the bounding rectangle itself? I've been assuming it already exists as the image outline.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect answer. Firstly, the `PointToClient` method translates a screen coordinates into the control's coordinates, but the `e.Location` already is in the control's coordinates: [proof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location(v=vs.110).aspx). Secondly, a `Image` is not a `Control`, so it cannot be placed on the form, except just draw it in the `Paint` event.